# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar elementos de un diccionario en un ListView en Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, listview

Intento mostrar los resultados de una consulta en una base de datos MongoDB pero no puedo mostrar los resultados pasados por `views.py`.

Aquí está la página donde los muestro iterando con un bucle for sobre `productos`:

```
{% extends "portfolio/base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<table class="table table-striped" align='center'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="center">Brand</th>
      <th align="center">Perfume Name</th>
      <th align="center">Gender</th>
      <th align="center">Theme</th>
      <th align="center">Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for element in products %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ element.q0.Results.0.Brand.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ element.q0.Results.0.Name }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Y este es views.py donde los solicito y envío.

```
import pymongo
import todo.config as config
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
from django.db.models import Q


username = config.username
password = config.password

client = pymongo.MongoClient(
        f"mongodb+srv://{username}:{password}@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net/ifresearch?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
collection = client.test.sephora_backup3

...

class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Perfume
    template_name = 'todo/search_similar_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        print(query)
        products = list(collection.find({"q0.Results.0.Name": {"$regex": query, "$options": "i"}}))
        print("products: ", products)
        return products
```

Hay resultados en los productos pero no se muestra nada.

Comment: Has probado a acceder en el loop a `{{ element.Brand.Name }}` en lugar de a `{{ element.q0.Results.0.Brand.Name }}`?

Answer (score 0):

ListView establece una variable llamada `object_list` en el contexto con los resultados de `get_queryset`. Así que si quiero usar mi propia variable necesito establecer `context_object_name` que usa ese nombre y si no intenta usar el nombre del modelo si la object_list lo tiene.

En mi caso, hice un bucle sobre `productos` pero no había ninguna variable de contexto. Debería haber puesto `context_object_name = 'products'`:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Perfume
    template_name = 'todo/search_similar_results.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
    
    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        print(query)
        products = list(collection.find({"q0.Results.0.Name": {"$regex": query, "$options": "i"}}))
        print("products: ", products)
        return products
```